# Why does "Partition by" have a major effect in the result here?

Tags: sql

This is the source table

```
Name        Occupation
-----------------
Meera       Singer
Priya       Singer
Ashley      Professor
Ketty       Professor
Christeen   Professor
Samantha    Doctor
Jenny       Doctor
Julia       Actor
Maria       Actor
Jane        Actor
```

```
SELECT
[Doctor],
[Professor],
[Singer],
[Actor] 
FROM
(SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by occupation ORDER BY name_) rn,
     [name_],
     [Occupation] 
 FROM 
     Occupations
) AS source 
PIVOT
(
MAX(name_) FOR [occupation] IN ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])
)as pvt
ORDER BY rn
```

the result is

`Jenny      Ashley      Meera   Jane`

`Samantha   Christeen   Priya   Julia`

`null       Ketty       null    Maria`

But when I do not use (partition by occupation)

the result is weird, like this

`null       Ashley      null       null`

`null       Christeen   null       null`

`null       null        null       Jane`

`Jenny      null        null       null`

`null       null        null       Julia`

`null       Ketty       null       null`

`null       null        null       Maria`

`null       null        Meera      null`

`null       null        Priya      null`

`Samantha   null        null       null`

Why is it so?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because MySQL does not support `pivot`.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I used MySQL only :/

Comment: . . Then your code would generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Because `partition by` restarts the numbering for each occupation.  So, the values go from `1` to `3`.

Without the `partition by`, the numbering goes from `1` to `10`.

Pivot is quite confusing, actually, because it returns a separate row when there are discrete values for the non-pivoted columns in the source.  Hence, you will get at least 11 rows without the `partition by`.  (This is just one of the reasons why I have a strong preference for conditional aggregation instead of `pivot`.)